# Use type of inheriting class in superclass

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

Consider the following code...:

```
class Car {
    public static createInstance():Car {
        return new this();
    }
}

class Ferrari extends Car {
    fast:boolean = true;
}

class AutoCycle extends Car {
    slow:boolean = true;
}

let myCar:Ferrari = Ferrari.createInstance();
```

...This will give me the error `Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'Ferrari'` with the following explanation: `Property 'fast' is missing in type 'Car'`

Of course I could prevent this error by skipping the type after `let myCar` or omit the return type of `createInstance`. Another option would be to do a type cast at the assignment.

But where's the fun in using **Type**Script, if I must refrain from using types properly? ;-)

**Hence my question:** Is there a way to do something like

```
public static createInstance():this { //...
```

(Where `this` is to be internally auto-replaced by `Ferrari` in my example)?

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863, so I'd assume that there isn't a way that doesn't involve extra casts/generics.

Comment: @y2bd Ah... thanks! I've been googling for ages, but I missed that!
I'd actually accept that as **the answer**, if you'd post as an answer!